# How to place text in bottom of an image (Polaroid image like)

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to make a polaroid image like. In which the image have a text in the bottom. I tried every instruction but failed to do so.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div id="Places" class="gallery">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/babot1.jpg" alt="bobat1">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/lhouse1.jpg" alt="bobat1">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/babot1.jpg" alt="bobat1">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my css code that I use

```
div.gallery{
border:2px solid #ddd;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:100px;
margin-bottom:30px;
border-radius:3px;

width:98%;
}
div.gallery::before{
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
div.gallery ul{
list-style-type:none;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0 auto;
}
div.gallery li a img {
margin: 20px 20px 21px 20px;
width: 28.50%;
float:left;
padding-bottom:50px;
}
```

EDIT 1:
 Here is the sample photo of what I got.
[image]

Comment: How is it failing? Go into more details. Don't just dump code.

Comment: @zero298 the text go outside the picture. Ill edit the post and add some photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<figure>` + `<figcaption>` have been designed for this.

To make it Polaroid like, here's what I'd do:

```css
figure {
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 7px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 2px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
figure img {
  display: block;
}
figcaption {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0 .5rem;
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<figure>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" />
   <figcaption>This would be a caption</figcaption>
 </figure>
 <figure>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/250x350" />
   <figcaption>This would be another caption</figcaption>
 </figure>
```

Please note you're currently floating the `<img>` tags. If you want the above to work, you need to ***remove the following*** from your current CSS:

```
div.gallery li a img {
  margin: 20px 20px 21px 20px;
  width: 28.50%;
  float:left;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
```

You can float your `<figure>`s instead.

Comment: great! that work perfeclty. Can you please explain me what I did wrong and how this code is different from mine? if its not a trouble.

Comment: You were floating your images. positioning them on the left side of your container and telling the rest of content to flow around them. To better understand floats, your should probably [read this](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 0):

there is an html tag to do what you want:

```html
<figure>
  <img src="myImage.jpg" alt="my image">
  <figcaption>This is my image</figcaption>
 </figure>
```

Comment: its the same result

Answer (score -2):

Put your text inside a div, position it absolute and give it a z-index of 90 or higher.

```
<div id="txt">This is a title</div>

<style>
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
</style>
```

Comment: Thsi has to be the laziest answer I have ever seen.